# Check the logs and abort the jobs on the basis of the count received

Tags: unix, datastage

For my code ,  I have 5 logs generated for 5 different tables . I have to find for which table the records are not loaded correctly .

Logs generated
NWPR_TempLoad_CSP_11.log:  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
NWPX_TempLoad_CSP_11.log:  326 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
PRAD_TempLoad_CSP_11.log:  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
PRER_TempLoad_CSP_11.log:  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
PROV_TempLoad_CSP_11.log:  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
PRSQ_TempLoad_CSP_11.log:  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
PRWM_TempLoad_CSP_11.log:  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.

Here we can see that for NWPX 326 were not loaded due to data errors . so I want the job to abort and in the error message we neeed to print , job aborted for NWPX load

Answer (score 0):

One option is to define a reject link from the Connector with which you write the target table.
With a reject link you can specify to abort the job if number of rows on that reject link is >= 1

The job log should have the information about the rejected record anyways.

For more details the stages and exact requirements should be described in more detail.

Comment: In the execute command stage I used this command                           grep 'Rows not loaded due to data errors.' File.log|grep [' '][1-9]|cut -d ' ' -f1|cut -c-4  .. if we have value received from this command .. I want to abort the job . This activity needs to be done in datastage

Comment: So you are talking about a Sequence?! Do you want to abort the Sequence depending on the result of the Execute Command stage? This information is not clear and not part of you question above....

Comment: Yes I want to abort the sequencer

Comment: You could use a nested condition and "fork" depending on the result of your execute command result. If you found errors route it to a Terminator activity. Please note for future questions that these kind of details really influence the answer and should be provided in the initial question. Thanks