# Abort the job on the basis of value received from execute command stage

Tags: datastage

My task is , I have 7 logs generated , 
A_TempLoad_CSP_11.log:  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
B_TempLoad_CSP_11.log:  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
C_TempLoad_CSP_11.log:  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
D_TempLoad_CSP_11.log:  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
E_TempLoad_CSP_11.log:  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
F_TempLoad_CSP_11.log:  2 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
G_TempLoad_CSP_11.log:  4 Rows not loaded due to data error
Here for F and G the count of rows not loaded is greater than 0 , I want the job to abort if for any of these the number of rows not loaded is greater than 0 , and in the director , I want this to be mentioned that Job aborted F and G .

Eg: Job failed for F and G

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check the logs and abort the jobs on the basis of the count received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52533969/check-the-logs-and-abort-the-jobs-on-the-basis-of-the-count-received)

Answer (score 0):

You can Keep a reject link for the same where data would be collected. Now link that dataset to a transformer which will have stage variables doing a count. The moment it gets increased to 1 from 0 map it to a job abort stage. This might work.